# Dynamically set value in Rails javascript asset based on Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a js file used for Recurly:

```
(function() {

  // Required
  Recurly.config({
    subdomain: 'MYSUBDOMAIN',
    currency: 'USD'
  });

})();
```

I'd like to be able to switch the subdomain attribute based on my Rails environment but keep this javascript available to the asset pipeline.  Is this possible within asset pipeline or what is the best way to achieve the equivalent functionality?

Comment: Hi Barry, welcome to SO! Don't forget to give other users feedback in the form of upvotes/acceptance if an answer works for you. Or, if an answer doesn't work, leave a comment about why it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a disappointingly hacky solution but you could set a global variable in the `<head>` of your document before your asset pipelined JS is included and then use that variable later, e.g.:

In your `application.html.erb`:

```
<head>
    ...
    <%= javascript_tag "var subdomain = '#{request.subdomains.join(".")}';" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    ...
</head>
```

And in your JS:

```
(function() {

  // Required
  Recurly.config({
    subdomain: subdomain,
    currency: 'USD'
  });

})();
```

Comment: Thanks!  doing something like this:
   `var subdomain = '#{RECURLY_SUBDOMAIN}';"`
with this placed in a constants file under config/initializer does not seem to compile the text, though...:
`RECURLY_SUBDOMAIN="MYSUBDOMAIN"`

Thoughts?  I'm guessing this is me being a newbie with ruby var scope more than anything, I hope.  However, I guess this doesn't directly answer my original question...  Is there no way to get to rails environment yet because asset pipeline is being compiled before any rails initializers are happening?

Comment: The `var subdomain...` code is actually boring old JavaScript. What that's doing is injecting a Ruby variable into a JS variable so it's available to the rest of your JS. And yes, you're correct about what you can (or more can't) do in the asset pipeline. Essentially, you only have access to the environment at compile time, i.e. you can't access the request object because your assets are already built and being served as static files.